# Is there a single word that could describe the phrase "makes it look easy"?

Tags: single-word-requests, phrases

As an example, consider this sentence:

When Roger Federer plays tennis, he just "makes it look so easy".

A single word or maybe a smaller phrase that I could replace it with?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

"Roger Federer plays tennis effortlessly".

It is shorter, but "makes it looks easy" is better writing, IMHO. Brevity is not ALWAYS the soul of wit.

Comment: Yes, but "Brevity is the soul of lingerie." (Dorothy Parker)

Comment: Brilliant! I laughed out loud...had not heard that one.

Comment: Does effortlessly not imply that it **actually** requires no effort, rather than **seeming** to not require any effort? Federer might be exhausted by the end, he simply doesn't show it. Then it's not effortless.

Comment: @Flater Quite so. "Roger Federer appears to play tennis effortlessly" or "Roger Federer plays match-winning tennis that looks effortless", for example, would be more accurate. _Effortless,_ however, is a great answer.

Comment: @rajah9 is it correct if add "to" before "look"?: "makes it to look easy"

Comment: Sounds unnatural and not an idiom in AmE to say *makes it to look easy.

Comment: @rajah9 Can you tell me if there is some rule about this? I just don't know.

Comment: Not sure there is a rule, but you might might want to search this site for dropped infinitives.

Comment: @rajah9 I suspect that that's a typo, and Boyep intended to write "Makes it look TOO easy".

Comment: Nah. Earlier comment said "to" before "look."

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other answers which have discussed your specific example, if you want to generalize a task is easy for someone expert at it, the popular phrases are

That was a "*piece of cake*" for him

That was "*easy as pie*" for him

and a single word,

That was a "*[cakewalk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/cakewalk)*" for him

Examples from the link above -

> "winning the tournament was a cakewalk for him"; "invading Iraq won't
>   be a cakewalk"

Comment: So the original sentence could be rephrased as "For Roger Federer, tennis is a cakewalk"?

Comment: @Frust: Grammatically Yes. But in reality, I would say "That match was an absolute cakewalk for Roger" and it would be correct. For Roger might not feel tennis is always a cakewalk.

Comment: I guess when you say "cakewalk", it would mean that it was an easy match for Roger. But when I say "makes it look easy", what I am trying to convey here is, when Roger plays the game, it doesn't matter how tough his opponent is, but he seems to play it in an effortless manner as @Chris B. Behrens put it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think there is such a one word version of that idea in English.

To say Roger Federer plays tennis "effortlessly" is decidedly NOT the same thing as him making it *look* easy.  In fact, the magic of some gifted athletes--this is often said of figure ice skaters--is that they make something that is, even for them, obviously difficult and full of effort *look* easy.

Comment: Agreed - there is a difference between merely doing something effortlessly and doing something in a way that makes it APPEAR effortless. But it was the closest thing I could come up with that was also shorter...that's part of way I recommended not using it :).

Answer (score 2):

You can use the phrase "and as always, it seems so effortless for him."  In the sentence it would be "That match seemed so effortless for Roger Federer, as always."

Answer (score 1):

@Chris B. Behrens correctly identifies the intended meaning in OP's context, but the question title is at the very least ambiguous.

We can assume that when Roger Federer plays tennis, his primary concern is to win the match. He's not really interested in showing others how easy it is to become a world-class player. OP's sentence is a simple description of how he plays (or *appears to play*, since I'm sure in reality it's not at all easy, even for him).

On the other hand, if a skilled teacher **makes it look easy** he is doing something totally different, and he may in fact need to put considerable effort into successfully [demystifying](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=demystify&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=c1dBTtuGHsXLhAfJ263LCQ&ved=0CBgQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=f21c08eea83b11fc&biw=1376&bih=916) his subject.

Comment: I understand the ambiguity in the question title. I guess it should be "makes it look easy" in the context of a person 'doing/working' on something rather than actually "making things seem easier to understand" for someone else.

Comment: @venividivamos: If we're going to be precise, *"making things seem easier to understand"* isn't really what you want a good teacher to do. You want him to *really* make them easier to understand, not just *seem so*. Unlike in Federer's case, where we don't really care how hard it *really* is for him - just that he doesn't *seem* to be struggling.

Answer (score 1):

A few other options are:

to perform in a *facile*, *fluent*, or *adroit* manner,

or to perform with *aplomb*, *facility*, *fluency*, or *composure*.

In some contexts you could even use *nonchalant* or *insouciant*.

Even though it may not directly be a good answer to the OP's question, I thought it would be good to mention the Dictionary.com word of the day: *ballon*, which was the impetus to pose myself the same question the OP did. This refers to the quality a skilled ballerina possesses to be able to appear to float.

Answer (score 0):

Sprezzatura- a nonchalant stance to conceal the exertion and thought behind the required art and actual effort. - studied carelessness

Comment: Hi Danny, welcome to EL&U. This is a great word, but you haven't cited and linked to a source for your definition, so readers can't tell whether it's true or you've just made it up. An answer on EL&U is expected to be *authoritative, detailed, and explain why it is correct*. If you [edit] your answer to add a published definition of *sprezzatura* (linked to the source) and ideally some real examples of its use, I would be delighted to upvote your post. For further guidance, see [answer] and take the EL&U **[Tour]** :-)